# OpenGL ES and Default iPhone UI components

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es

So I am rather experienced with OpenGL on the desktop platform and am trying to integrate it with my iOS development experience.  I have created several large scale iOS applications so I have a good understanding of that process as well.  I was wondering if anyone knows of any useful techniques to integrate iOS UI components with an OpenGL scene, or if that is even possible.  I apologize if this is to general.  I can refine it if necessary.

For example, say you have an iPad application that has a table and whatnot on the left, and you want to add a little 3D OpenGL window on the right. (Perhaps a chart or something that the user can interact with?)  This would not be for a game or anything, but more for my understanding on how to smoothly integrate the different platforms.  Any advice or links that the community could provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GL-Views do not have to cover the entire screen. A great and very easy to understand example is the sound=recorder [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802) iphone app within the iOS SDK.

This example uses a small GL-View for displaying a peak-level-meter of the audio signal; GLLevelMeter.

Hope this helps...

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I am looking for :)

Comment: Found it and tried to compile it with Xcode 4 SDK 4.3 - works just fine.

Comment: To expand on Till's answer, OpenGL is displayed via a CAEAGLLayer; usually you create a custom UIView subclass with CAEAGLLayer nominated as the layerClass. What you then have is a normal UIView that you can put anywhere you want, according to any drawing hierarchy, around/above/underneath any other type of UIView, and to which you can draw OpenGL content. If you're writing a game you'll often make that view the only thing and use a CADisplayLink to give you a refresh-connected update timer but neither is required.

Comment: Wow great answers guys.  I think I understand what exactly is going on.  Thanks for the help...